# Is there a way to disable popup blocker in Safari using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mime-types, mime

I know this is a very vague question. But in my current application, I need to download the xls file from ajax response. So I used "window.location", and it worked out perfectly in chrome, firefox and IE.

But safari is throwing an error **"resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type 'application/vnd.ms-excel'"**. For this I have changed the code little bit from "window.location" to "window.open('url','_blank')". It solved the mime type error. But when popup blocker is enabled in safari, it is not even prompting the user to give permission to open popup. But all other browsers did that.

So my question is! Is there any possibility that, I can turn off the popup blocker in safari either using javascript or jQuery (I Know we cannot override the browser settings using the js or jQuery)? Or at-least can we know weather pop-up blocker is enabled or not?